# Hugo won't render front matter variables when I publish to Netlify

Tags: html, templates, blogs, hugo, yaml-front-matter

I am building a hugo blog site and I have some front matter that I would like to get rendered in the layouts. When I view the results on my localhost:1313, I can see the front matter being populated, but when I host the site on Netlify, the front matter and partial files won't render.

I'm not sure what else to do. I've cleared the console of any errors, made sure my content files match the layout files etc.

Any help?

Here is the link to the live netlify site: https://stoic-meninsky-a5758a.netlify.app/

Here is my directory structure:

```
-content
 -about
  -_index.md
 -blog
  -_index.md
   -post-1.md
 -_index.md

-layouts
 -_default
  -baseOf.html
 -about
  -section.html
 -blog
  -section.html
  -single.html
 _index.html
```

This is a sample file that is pulled from one of my content markdown files:

```
---
title: "The Herman Show | Blog"
linktitle: "Blog"
draft: true
newsletter: "This is the newsletter"
---
```

This is how I call the front matter: `<p>{{ .Params.newsletter }}</p>`

This is how I loop over the section pages to get a navbar

```html
{{ range .Site.Sections }}
  <li><a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .LinkTitle }}</a></li>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your markdown files in the content directory are marked to: `drafts:false`